# How to open youtube video in fullscreen mode with puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, youtube, puppeteer, screenshot

I've tried few things i.e.

```
await page.click('.ytp-fullscreen-button.ytp-button') // click on fullscreen button
await page.keyboard.press('f') // press f to open fullscreen
await page.keyboard.down('f'); await page.keyboard.up('f'); //similar to previous
await page.evaluate(() => document.getElementsByClassName('ytp-fullscreen-button ytp-button')[0].click()) //injecting js and using it to click on fullscreen button
```

but nothing worked, is there a way to enter fullscreen mode on youtube using puppeteer?

Answer (score 4):

This seems working for me:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, defaultViewport: null });

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  // David Lynch's Weather Report 7/22/21
  await page.goto('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MlyNWpf1N0s');

  await page.waitForSelector('.ytp-fullscreen-button.ytp-button');

  await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.querySelector('.ytp-fullscreen-button.ytp-button').click();
  });
} catch (err) { console.error(err); }
```

Comment: oh, well, I found out the problem thanks to you, my code also works but only with headless set to false, the problem now is I need to host it on EC2 and there is an error when I try to launch browser in non-headless mode, but hopefully I will be able to make it work. Thanks :)